# How to fast exit from entity framework foreach query loop?

Tags: vb.net, performance, entity-framework, foreach

### Question

I am trying to implement something like this:

```
For Each person In db.Persons.Where(Function(x) x.Name = requestedName)
  If AbortRequested Then Exit For
  MyFunc(person)
Next
```

I expected that the Exit For will fast-finish the loop, but I was wrong. If normal query requires 60seconds, then aborted query will require the same time: 60 seconds. The only difference between aborted and not-aborted query is that the "MyFunc(person)" is not executed for the rest of persons.

But I need abort to shorten the loop time. What should I do?

### Solution

Based on peer's advice I implemented following code and it works fine:

```
Dim tokenSource As New CancellationTokenSource()
Dim taskGetTests = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
    For Each person In db.Persons.Where(Function(x) x.Name = requestedName)
      If AbortRequested Then
        tokenSource.Cancel()
        Exit For
      End If
      MyFunc(person)
    Next
  End Sub , tokenSource.Token)
taskGetTests.Wait(tokenSource.Token)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the MyFunc call async or use tasks, this will allow you to return before the function MyFunc returns a value.

[MSDN on Cancel tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)